# Switching between graphics cards Nvidia or ATI in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opencl

I'm going to run my project on servers with a lot of ATI and NVidia Tesla. How can I optimize the use of graphics cards? Can I choose the specific video card when I start the instance application?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of "specific":

1. If you just want to select between NVIDIA and AMD, you can use `CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR` with `clGetPlatformInfo` and look for "AMD" or "NVIDIA".
2. If you want to get back to a specific GPU you've used before, you can use `CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID` with `clGetDeviceInfo` and compare the saved value.
3. Sometimes those are the same in a dual-GPU installation. Use vendor extensions to get more specific (see [Associating OpenCL device ids with GPU](https://anteru.net/2014/08/01/2483/)).

Comment: This is good way if I use only OpenCL. But I use OpenCV functions, which are implemented both on CUDA and OpenCL. I can switch between CUDA and OpenCL, but I want switch between GPUs of one vendor or run instance of my application with specific GPU (by id or name)

Comment: Indeed. I realized after I submitted my answer that your question was about OpenCV but my answer was just OpenCL. Sorry.